# How to set sectionIndexTitlesForTableView for using localized strings like contacts app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, localization, contacts

Right now, I have a array of English contact including firstname and lastname etc. I want to localized these names to other languages. But how to set sectionIndexTitlesForTableView for tableview according to the language changes in settings.? I remembered there is a api for this, but I just forgot the method name.